# How to set different colors in HTML in one statement?

Tags: html, text

I'm thinking of having different color of text in one line. How could that be possible?

```
<p style="color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20"> My Name is: 

 <"color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20"> Tintincute </p>
```

I would like to have a different color for Tintincute but in one line the problem with this, the name went down one space.

This is the code example:

```
<p style="color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold">All fields marked with   <style="color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold">*</color> <style="color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold">are required</p>
```

### Update

@Phil: I tried using the code, but it didn't work. The code itself was shown on the page. This is how I did it:

```
<div style="color:red">[+validationmessage+]</div>
p.detail {color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20 }
span.name {color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20 }
<p class="detail">My Name is: <span class="name">Tintincute</span> </p>
```

Comment: This is a programming question and therefore should be on Stack Overflow, however, there's not a lot of information here. What code do you have already (for example).

Comment: @ChrisF: please check my code example above. Thanks

Comment: This is what you want: `<span style="color:black;">My Name is:</span>&nbsp;<span style="color:red;">Tintincute</span>`. Spans don't block and therefore introduce a new line.

Comment: @slhck: Thanks for suggestion, but I would like it to be that the whole sentence would be in one line. By introducing the "&nbsp;" this command, this will introduce a single line,

Comment: I'll post a new answer in a minute.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You could use CSS for this and create classes for the elements. So you'd have something like this

```
p.detail { color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20 }
span.name { color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20 }
```

Then your HTML would read:

```
<p class="detail">My Name is: <span class="name">Tintinecute</span> </p>
```

It's a lot neater then inline stylesheets, is easier to maintain and provides greater reuse.

Here's the complete HTML to demonstrate what I mean:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <style type="text/css">
    p.detail { color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20 }
    span.name { color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20 }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <p class="detail">My Name is: <span class="name">Tintinecute</span> </p>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll see that I have the stylesheet classes in a style tag in the header, and then I only apply those classes in the code such as `<p class="detail"> ... </p>`. Go through the w3schools tutorial, it will only take a couple of hours and will really turn you around when it comes to styling your HTML elements. If you cut and paste that into an HTML document you can edit the styles and see what effect they have when you open the file in a browser. Experimenting like this is a great way to learn.

Comment: what about if I don't use CSS, will it also work with HTML alone?

Comment: Yes, if you use inline stylesheets like in your original example: <p style="color:#4C4C4C;font-weight:bold;font-family:Calibri;font-size:20">My Name is: <span style="color:#FF0000;font-weight:bold;font-family:Tahoma;font-size:20">Tintinecute</span> </p> <-works. But I'd recommend using CSS, it will make your life a lot easier. If you don't know CSS this is a great time to start learning.

Comment: Thanks @Phil: I will try your suggestion if that will work with my code.

Comment: Thanks for the link I tried using the code you suggested but it didn't work. if you check my edited one, you will see...

Comment: w3schools is supposed to have many errors. http://www.tizag.com/cssT/ or similar resources are much better.

Comment: @Phil: What about the div shall I ignore it then?

Comment: @Phil: You know I'm making an eform and trying to find out where to insert the code for this if I want to change the font-style: <tr>
        <td><label for="firstName" style="margin:0.5em">First Name:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="firstName" size="60" maxlength="60" eform="First Name::1" /></td>
    </tr>

Comment: @Phil: Do I have to put that in my style sheet as well?

Comment: Yes create a class with the style in it and where your HTML element reads style="..." change that to class="class_name".

Answer (score 19):

Use the `span` tag

```
<style>
    .redText
    {
        color:red;
    }
    .blackText
    {
        color:black;
        font-weight:bold;
    }
</style>

<span class="redText">My Name is:</span>&nbsp;<span class="blackText">Tintincute</span>
```

It's also a good idea to avoid inline styling. Use a custom CSS class instead.

Comment: Just a quick question for you: how can I integrate this to a div code? Especially if my code starts with: "div style="color:red">"

Comment: If your spans are inside the div, the div's style will be overridden by your custom classes (it will still work). Does that answer your question?

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes, but I think I should better take the div out. It seems to work but I'm still trying to figure out how to change the font-style of the others if I'm making an eform.

Answer (score 5):

How about using FONT tag?

Like:

```
H<font color="red">E</font>LLO.
```

Can't show example here, because this site doesn't allow font tag use.

Span style is fast and easy too.

Comment: The HTML Font element is deprecated and should not be used anymore. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font

Answer (score 2):

```css
.rainbow {
  background-image: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  background-image: gradient( linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0, #f22), color-stop(0.15, #f2f), color-stop(0.3, #22f), color-stop(0.45, #2ff), color-stop(0.6, #2f2),color-stop(0.75, #2f2), color-stop(0.9, #ff2), color-stop(1, #f22) );
  color:transparent;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  background-clip: text;
}
```

```html
<h2><span class="rainbow">Rainbows are colorful and scalable and lovely</span></h2>
```

Answer (score 1):

I know it's kinda **clunky** but it does the work

if you have, for example:

```
<a>Color1 Color2</a>
```

You can just style part of the text inside

```
<a>Color1 <a style=color:yellow>Color2</a></a>
```

output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```html
<p style="font-weight:bold"> ¿ is this color   
                <span style="color:red; font-weight:bold"> red? </span> 
                <span style="font-weight:bold"> ? </span>   
            </p>
```