# How to set different colors in the title for WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am new to WordPress. And I want to set diffrent colors in the title of the customizr theme.

How could I finish that? I know that if withou WordPress, I could use css and span tag finish that like [how to set different colors in html in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913234/how-to-set-different-colors-in-html-in-one-statement).

But how could I do that in a WordPress theme.

Answer (score 0):

You still have to use css.  If you want to edit the theme, locate the theme folder first. Go to wp-content/themes/customizr  or whatever the theme folder is.

Usually the title can be found in few different files: single.php, page.php, index.php, etc., it depends from theme to theme. Many developers include templates inside each of these files too. Again, everything changes from theme to theme.

My recommendations is to create a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) to perform any customization. Also I recommend reading the codex to know more about WordPress development and [theme development](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development), that way you learn more how things come together and work.