# how to css md-tab label in angularjs

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-material

**Markup :**

```
md-tab label="Current ({{ctrl.ongoing_assignments.length}})"
```

**Required Output :**

> Current (1) <===== i want the number will be in red background with round shape like notification in facebook

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code people can use to reproduce the problem. That code should be… https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: but i did provide?

Answer (score 2):

If you want this styling to apply to only this element you can do:

In a css file:

```
.reference{ 
    background-color: red;
}
```

Your html:

```
md-tab class="reference" label="Current ({{ctrl.ongoing_assignments.length}})"
```

---

If you want this styling to apply to all the md-tab labels you can do:

```
md-tab {
   background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the css file is included in your project?

Answer (score 1):

From your question i dont know this solution is a step in success or not, 
but see if its helpful then i can make modifications to achieve the desired result.

Currently, 
2 tabs are shown: 

- first one is a normal tab, and 
 - second one changes background color on being active.

```js
angular.module('MyApp', ['ngMaterial'])
            .controller('AppCtrl', function ($scope, $mdSidenav) {
                $scope.ButtonText = "Test Button";

                $scope.buttonClick = function() {
                    alert("First Angular Material App");
                };
            });
```

```css
.other-div md-tabs .md-tab.md-active .md-ripple-container {
  color: rgb(248,187,208);
  background: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
.other-div md-tabs .md-tab.md-active {
    color: green;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>First App Angular Material</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.css" />
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/angular/bower-material/v0.10.0/angular-material.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
      <md-tabs md-selected="1" md-stretch-tabs="auto" md-align="bottom" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-center-tab md-swipe-content>
        <md-tab label="tab1">
          <md-tab-body>
            <h1>Welcome to first tab</h1>
            <md-tab-body>
          </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="tab2">
          <md-tab-body>
            <h1>Welcome to Second tab</h1>
            <md-tab-body>
          </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="tab3">
          <md-tab-body>
            <h1>Welcome to Third tab</h1>
            <md-tab-body>
          </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </div>
    
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl" class='other-div'>
      <md-tabs md-selected="1" md-stretch-tabs="auto" md-align="bottom" md-dynamic-height md-border-bottom md-center-tab md-swipe-content>
        <md-tab label="tab1">
          <md-tab-body>
            <h1>Welcome to first tab</h1>
            <md-tab-body>
          </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="tab2">
          <md-tab-body>
            <h1>Welcome to Second tab</h1>
            <md-tab-body>
          </md-tab>
            <md-tab label="tab3">
          <md-tab-body>
            <h1>Welcome to Third tab</h1>
            <md-tab-body>
          </md-tab>
      </md-tabs>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for this example bro in my post you can see the label tag there was a angular caller like this "{{}}" it means there somthing that i call in my controller and that number is the one that i need to be with color

Comment: at your example the label name is "TAB 2" with color but i want is TAB<<===no color, 2<<<<< with color only

Comment: @wiwit its not possible, as the html rendered by `md-tab` for showing label is `<span class="ng-scope">tab2</span>`.You can see that the label which we provide is kept inside a span tag and the value `tab2` is a single entity. So it can be colored with a single color only, if you want 2 color then other value must be inside different span tag like `<span class="ng-scope">tab<span>2</span></span>`, but we don't have our hold on the html rendered by `md-tab`, so we cannot color single entity with 2 different color.

Comment: See for Reference : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913234/how-to-set-different-colors-in-html-in-one-statement/#answer-6913337

Comment: that was sad bro T_T give me rope i will hang myself

Comment: @wiwit if time is not an issue for this problem, then may be you can go for building your own tab panel. As with that you will have control over html and can make as expected for required result.