# Display another style of a portion of a link

Tags: css, hover

I have a styled link. Now, I would like to have another style on a few letters of the link, which is another colour, on hover.

Example:

**THIS IS NORMAL LINK**

**THIS IS NORM*AL* LINK** in hover where ***AL*** is Italic and in other colour.

Comment: show your code and what you tried so far

Comment: Nothing yet. I could not find any similar solution thus far.

Comment: do the letter that you want to change is fixed?

Comment: What do you mean with that?

Comment: Hey @De1an, Please update your post with some code, of what you have tried so far.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set different colors in html in one statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6913234/how-to-set-different-colors-in-html-in-one-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your wannted text in `span` and style it `:hover`

```css
a:hover span{
font-style: italic;
color:red;
}
```

```html
<a>THIS IS NORM<span>AL</span> LINK</a>
```

Comment: may I ask you a question

Comment: Yes of course... You can also post question and show me the link

Comment: It's not about coding its about posting answer, my question is "Is it legal to edit someone's wrong answer to right and tell everyone not to post the same answer?"

Comment: Ho It really do not have an absolute answer... You can post this qusetion here https://meta.stackexchange.com/ (under discussion tag) (if you post answer show me the link... but prevent of using spesific user's name... or spesific behavior  to your question)

Comment: @Prince I show your question  and upvote... let's see what people say

Comment: I hope we'll get a definite answer for this.

Answer (score 2):

try this example

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
span.ex1:hover, span.ex1:active {font-style: italic; color: red;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p>Mouse over the links to see them change layout.</p>


<p><a  href="default.asp">THIS IS NORM<span class="ex1">AL</span> LINK</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```css
a{
   color:#333;
   text-transform:uppercase;
   text-decoration:none;
 }
 
a:hover span{
    font-style:italic;
    color:red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is norm<span>al</span> link</a>
```

Comment: so may I know why are you keep copy pasting this comment everywhere?

Comment: Ok I appreciate that, but the first answer isn't made originally by the user you have edited the correct answer

Comment: Is it legal to edit someone's wrong answer to right and pretend that it was correct?

Comment: That's the point why am I posting my answer. I've created my answer and it solely created by me 100% not edited.

Comment: I am not saying its wrong, but when you posted your answer there were already 3 answers all having the same logic.So you must have corrected the person or posted the answer. You did the required, i am not blaming, but i was making sure to stop multiple same approach answers to the question. Please see my point.